# Using ImageMagick to create an image from a PDF...efficiently

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I'm using ImageMagick to create a tiny JPG thumbnail image of an already-uploaded PDF. The code works fine. It's a WordPress widget, though this isn't necessarily WordPress specific.

I'm unfamiliar with ImageMagick, so I was hoping somebody could tell me if this looks terrible or isn't following some best practices of some sort, or if I'm risking crashing the server.

My questions, specifically, are:

- Is that image cached, or does the server have to re-generate the image every time somebody views the page? If it *isn't* cached, what's the best way to make sure the server doesn't have to regenerate the thumbnail?
- I tried to create a separate folder (/thumbs) for ImageMagick to put all the images in, instead of cluttering up the WP upload folders with images of PDFs. It kept throwing a permission error, despite 777 permissions on the folder in my testing environment. Why? Do the source/destination directories have to be the same?
- Am I doing anything incorrectly/inefficiently here that needs to be improved?

The whole widget is on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WnSTEDm7

Relevant code:

```
<?php

if ( $url ) {       
    $pdf = $url;
    $info = pathinfo($pdf);
    $filename =  basename($pdf,'.'.$info['extension']);

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $file_path = str_replace( $uploads['baseurl'], $uploads['basedir'], $url );
    $dest_path = str_replace( '.pdf', '.jpg', $file_path );
    $dest_url = str_replace( '.pdf', '.jpg', $pdf );

    exec("convert \"{$file_path}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 60 $dest_path"); ?>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="widgetImg">
            <p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $filename; ?>"><?php echo "<img src='".$dest_url."' alt='".$filename."' class='blueBorder' />"; ?></a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="widgetText">
            <?php echo wpautop( $desc ); ?>

            <p><a class="downloadLink" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $filename; ?>">Download</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
?>
```

As you can see, the widget grabs whatever PDF is attached to the current page being viewed, creates an image of the first page of the PDF, stores it, then links to it in HTML.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saving as a jpg try adding -define to your code:

```
exec("convert -define jpeg:size=60x60 \"{$file_path}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 60 $dest_path"); ?>
```

60x60 is the finished size of your image - all it does is read in enough data to create the image so speeding up the read process.

Resize keeping aspect then crop to 60x60

```
exec("convert -define jpeg:size=60x60 \"{$file_path}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -thumbnail 60x60 -gravity center -crop 60x60+0+0 +repage $dest_path"); ?>
```

Comment: Cool, thank you for the suggestion. How does it know how to crop the image, though? I'd like a uniform thumbnail size, but I didn't trust the program to crop things appropriately/understandably.

Comment: Your geometry will still work as it is. I would resize with -thumbnail and then crop - code added above.

Answer (score 0):

So I think ImageMagick *was* re-generating the thumbnail on every page view. Pages with this widget would take an additional couple of seconds to load.

So, it now does a simple check to see if the thumbnail is already there:

```
if ( !file_exists( $dest_path ) ) {
    exec("convert \"{$file_path}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 60 $dest_path");
};
```

Pages that took ~5 seconds to load now take 2-3.

Regardless, I'm still interested to know if any PHP people think this could be done better.

Hope this code helps somebody out.

Comment: Maybe you could enhance the speed by generating the image after the upload is complete. This way your users won't get a delay because of the image generation. Combine this with some header management to prevent browsers from re-downloading the image when nothing has changed, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: the PDFs are added by site administrators from the back-end (WP media library), not end-users. The widget just displays a JPG of the cover page of a PDF, generated by ImageMagick, and gives them a download link.